# Speed very slow when Resync Hard disk with mdadm

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, mdadm

**Problem:** When I add `sda3` to `/dev/md3` the speed of two disk decrease... a lot, it decrease to ~100k

**Question about why it decrease the speed.**

1. It will be because the server is running in normal mode, and all services are in operation.... ? like mysql, apache, json, etc...
2. Is some connector bad, (connector from motherboard to hard disk)?
3. Configuration are bad? I tried modify `speed_limit_min`
4. The hard disk was new, and only did copy structure, the command that
   I use was 
    `sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk /dev/sda`
5. Maybe the hard disk isn't compatible with raid1?

**Some Information**

```
//Command for add sda device
mdadm --manage /dev/md3 --add /dev/sda3

// check status of resync
# cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md3 : active raid1 sda3[2] sdb3[0]
      970470016 blocks [2/1] [U_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.0% (43840/970470016) finish=29872.1min speed=541K/sec

md1 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      4194240 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

When I add the disk to `mdadm raid1`, the speed decrease a lot and in the other hard drive too.. **:S**

```
# hdparm -tT /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:     2 MB in 19.52 seconds = 104.94 kB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:   2 MB in 65.97 seconds =  31.04 kB/sec


//remove disk because resync is freezen server
mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda3 
mdadm /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda3
```

---

**Solutions that I tried**

```
# echo "5000" > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
# echo "50000" > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max
```

**Reference**: [here](http://www.gigahype.com/helpful-tips-speed-linux-sofware-raid-rebuild/)

---

Normal speed in `/dev/sda without` resync <-- new disk

```
# hdparm -tT /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   7512 MB in  2.00 seconds = 3758.92 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 150 MB in  3.02 seconds =  49.66 MB/sec
```

---

Normal speed in `/dev/sdb` without resync with mdadm  <-- good disk

```
# hdparm -tT /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
 Timing cached reads:   7000 MB in  2.00 seconds = 3502.26 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 248 MB in  3.01 seconds =  82.34 MB/sec
```

---

Command for show sdb disk partitions and sda

```
#lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdb                      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
|-sdb1                   8:17   0     4G  0 part
| `-md1                  9:1    0     4G  0 raid1 /
|-sdb2                   8:18   0     2G  0 part  [SWAP]
`-sdb3                   8:19   0 925.5G  0 part
  `-md3                  9:3    0 925.5G  0 raid1
    |-vg00-usr (dm-0)  252:0    0   105G  0 lvm   /usr
    |-vg00-var (dm-1)  252:1    0   720G  0 lvm   /var
    `-vg00-home (dm-2) 252:2    0    70G  0 lvm   /home
sda                      8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
|-sda1                   8:33   0     4G  0 part
| `-md1                  9:1    0     4G  0 raid1 /
|-sda2                   8:34   0     2G  0 part  [SWAP]
`-sda3                   8:35   0 925.5G  0 part
```

---

## **Extra information**

---

```
blockdev --getra /dev/md3
256
```

---

```
cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8       16  976762584 sdb
   8       17    4194304 sdb1
   8       18    2097152 sdb2
   8       19  970470104 sdb3
   9        1    4194240 md1
   9        3  970470016 md3
 252        0  110100480 dm-0
 252        1  754974720 dm-1
 252        2   73400320 dm-2
   8       32  976762584 sda
   8       33    4194304 sda1
   8       34    2097152 sda2
   8       35  970470104 sda3
```

---

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays

ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1  
ARRAY /dev/md3 level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sda3,/dev/sdb3
#ARRAY /dev/md11 level=raid1 num-devices=2 devices=/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1
```

---

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Tue Jun 28 21:37:54 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 4194240 (4.00 GiB 4.29 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 4194240 (4.00 GiB 4.29 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
Preferred Minor : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Jan  2 11:11:27 2017
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 4878c265:cddfb861:1f51fb89:78ee93fe
         Events : 0.581776

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
```

---

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md3
/dev/md3:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Tue Jun 28 21:37:54 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 970470016 (925.51 GiB 993.76 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 970470016 (925.51 GiB 993.76 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
Preferred Minor : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Jan  2 11:12:15 2017
          State : active, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 3719a2fe:5de22a92:1f51fb89:78ee93fe
         Events : 0.26462169

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       19        0      active sync   /dev/sdb3
       1       0        0        1      removed
```

---

## **smartctl with long test results**

---

This is the new dev, the new hard disk

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sda   

smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-106-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST1000DM003-1SB102
Serial Number:    Z9A4SRJX
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 092058fcf
Firmware Version: CC43
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Dec 31 13:54:02 2016 MST

==> WARNING: A firmware update for this drive may be available,
see the following Seagate web pages:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207931en
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223651en

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 241) Self-test routine in progress...
                                        10% of test remaining.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 104) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x1085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   073   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       22632891
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       1
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   100   253   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       25770426301
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       70
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       1
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   090   090   000    Old_age   Always       -       24 32 32
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   070   069   040    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 25/31)
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   030   025   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (0 25 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   010   009   000    Old_age   Always       -       22632891
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       69h+48m+11.238s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       21834581
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       798310

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 2
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 2 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 58 hours (2 days + 10 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 51 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff   2d+10:52:15.111  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  b0 d4 00 82 4f c2 00 00   2d+10:51:54.064  SMART EXECUTE OFF-LINE IMMEDIATE
  61 00 10 50 0c db 41 00   2d+10:51:54.064  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00   2d+10:51:54.064  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   2d+10:51:53.984  FLUSH CACHE EXT

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 58 hours (2 days + 10 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was in an unknown state.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  04 51 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ABRT

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff   2d+10:46:05.163  NOP [Abort queued commands]
  b0 d4 00 82 4f c2 00 00   2d+10:45:44.584  SMART EXECUTE OFF-LINE IMMEDIATE
  61 00 18 88 0f 44 42 00   2d+10:45:44.584  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  ea 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00   2d+10:45:44.584  FLUSH CACHE EXT
  b0 d0 01 00 4f c2 00 00   2d+10:45:43.477  SMART READ DATA

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Self-test routine in progress 10%        70         -
# 2  Extended captive    Interrupted (host reset)      90%        58         -
# 3  Extended captive    Interrupted (host reset)      90%        58         -
# 4  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%        58         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

---

Old disk, this dev is where all is working

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sdb

smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-106-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST1000DM003-1CH162
Serial Number:    S1D9YSS6
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 06106421b
Firmware Version: CC46
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Dec 31 13:52:22 2016 MST

==> WARNING: A firmware update for this drive is available,
see the following Seagate web pages:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207931en
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223651en

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  575) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 112) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   119   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       221092144
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   097   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       32
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   077   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       21764523466
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   087   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       11497
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       32
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   067   063   045    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 32/34)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       183
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   033   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (0 20 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       11232h+41m+23.205s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       55718050076
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       82556976137

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     11497         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      8059         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8042         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your new disk has some firmware or hardware related problem. This can be inferred by two datapoint:

- the slow beffered read (49 MB/s), which is much lower than the old disk
- the SATA command timeouts seen from the SMART report.

Check if a firmware update for your disk exists, and do the same for the motherboard/controller BIOS. If possible, try your new disk in another PC to have confirmation of the slow buffered read speed.

Comment: The problem here is theserver is in a dedicate hosting server, and i don't have access to it, i can't check the hard disk in another pc.. :S

Comment: So, ask for the substitution of the new, but failing, disk.

Comment: the problem is that this is a new hard drive, because the previous hard drive was failing.

Comment: Strange, the new disk has an older firmware. However md rebuild will kill IO performance until it's done, that's to be expected. You should wait for the resync to finish before making more tests.

Comment: BTW barracuda are terrible, terrible disks. The worst on the market. Avoid them if you can.